# Else statement not reaching the correct If for error

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently having a problem because I have a combo box converted into a dropdownlist box and if they do not choose the server inside of server then it will not let them log in. I've put an else statement but when they don't choose the server correctly then it'll pop up. I want to the program to use the correct if statement for that kind of error.

Code: (entire code)

```
 If txtUsername.Text = My.Settings.Username And txtPassword.Text = My.Settings.Password And cmbServers.Text = "Redox Server" Then
            stripStatus.Text = "Connecting to 'Redox Server; Please wait...'"
            frmRedox.Show()
            Me.Close()

        Else
            If txtUsername.Text = "" And txtPassword.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("Please input a username and password to login. If you do not have an account then you may create one.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Redox - Error")
            If cmbServers.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("Please select the server called 'Redox Server'.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Redox - Server Connectivity Error")

            End If
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: it is for one completely unclear what you want to achieve, and most likely your code snippet is too little info. you should post the complete If/Else/EndIf block maybe with unnecessary lines shortened ...

Comment: You have posted code that will show one message if both txtUsername a,d txtPasword are empty, then another message if cmbServers is empty. That is what will happen if the code is executed. If you are not seeing the messages you expect then either the code is not being executed, or the appropriate TextBoxes are not empty (but they could contain blanks).

Comment: that code is nonsense.  how can we tell where the logical errors are with missing IF and END IFs which are essential to code flow execution?

Comment: I've added the whole code, please review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did at least miss "**EndIf**" or "**ElseIf**".

```
Else
    If ... Then
        DoSomething
    EndIf
    If ... Then
        DoSomething
    EndIf
EndIf
```

Or probably this:

```
Else
    If ... Then
        DoSomething
    ElseIf ... Then
        DoSomething
    EndIf
EndIf
```